# Add content to on top of the header

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

I've defined the puppeteer option with the following options:

```
const options = {
  path,
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true,
  headerTemplate: '<div></div>',
  footerTemplate: '<div></div>',
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  scale: 0.75,
  margin: {
    top: '139px',
    bottom: '39px',
    right: '0px',
    left: '0px',
  },
}
```

and it adds correctly the header and the footer, but I wonder if it's possible to add content on top of the header/footer ?

[image]